# Problem connecting to the soketi on the server

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I am going to setup a websocket
I have used soketi package

But I am facing a problem in connecting to the web socket
which now i will get this error

code: 4001
message: "App key ---- does not exist."
event: "pusher:error"

In general, I have done this to set up the web socket:
soketi server :

sub domain : socket.example.com

installing
apt install -y git python3 gcc build-essential
npm install -g @soketi/soketi

soketi config json

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "port": 443,
    "appManager.array.apps": [
        {
            "id": "---",
            "key": "---",
            "secret": "----"
        }
    ]
}
```

broadcast :

```
'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
'encrypted' => true,
useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME') === 'https'
```

env config:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=---
PUSHER_APP_KEY=---
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=---
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
SOKETI_SSL_CERT=/etc/nginx/ssl/socket.example.com/----/server.crt
SOKETI_SSL_KEY=/etc/nginx/ssl/socket.wourki.com/----/server.key
```

run soketi
soketi start --config=soketi.json

Connect to WebSockets in the main project:
domain : example.com

broadcast

```
'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
'encrypted' => true,
useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME') === 'https'
```

env config

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=---
PUSHER_APP_KEY=---
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=---
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_HOST='socket.example.com'
```

laravel echo

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '----',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    forceTLS: true,
    wsHost:'socket.example.com',
    wsPort:6001,
    wssPort:443,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

So far, I have not had the experience of setting up a web socket. I would be grateful if you could guide me
Or introduce me to a tutorial for this

Comment: Error message is fairly clear, the key does not exist. Make sure you've cleared caches and restarted servers after making changes to your env files.

Comment: There is an app key
When wsHost uses the socket.example.com domain, I encounter this error, but when I comment wsHost, this error no longer exists.
It only connects to the pusher, not to the websocket server